# Why does hyper threaded or Multi-threaded CPU matter?

Tags: multithreading, cpu

Since single CPU could only execute one instruction at a time. Basically, what Multi-threaded CPU does is switch back and forth between multiple threads within single core. Since single-threaded & singl-core CPU could do multitasking by context switch between processes, why does Multi-threaded CPU matter?

Comment: This question is not appropriate for SO. HT is just a next-level ILP -- instead of extracting parallelism between instructions from a single thread, it's between multiple threads.

Comment: Why does Burger King hire more than one cashier during peak times? Couldn't you just have one cashier running from register to register?

Comment: First, [superscalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar) processors can execute multiple instructions in parallel. Second, even in a scalar processor, a single thread of execution will experience stalls from [hazards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28computer_architecture%29). Third, software context switches are much slower than the hardware equivalent, so tend only to be used for the very long stalls associated with I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up quite a few things here ...
First of all : hardware-threads have next to nothing in common with software-threads. As far as i know, there can only be `n` hardware-threads on a CPU whereas `n` is the amount of real or virtual CPU-cores (an ALU, for example)

Context switching is done to allow the **illusion** of parallelism **on one single core**.
Now : since there are no CPUs without several cores anymore, every CPU supports MT which effectively enables somewhat **real** parallelism - multiple calculations can be done at the same time yet the result has to be pipelined.

Modern CPUs even simulate additional cores - thats possible because there is a time-gap between result-delivery and command-dispatch, AFAIR - this can be used for additional calculations ... thats called `hyperthreading` and **can** boost your performance a bit.